# what is the sample rate of spotify stream (libspotify)?

Tags: spotify

What is the sample rate of spotify stream?

The call back function "music_delivery" in libspotify example playtrack takes audio format from libspotify directly. Is the audio decoded to be raw wave data already? Is the sample rate 44.1kHz/16bit by default? Does the libspotify convert the original audio sample rate to be 44.1KHz/16bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The audio you get in the `music_delivery` callback is indeed raw PCM data. The sample rate and bit depth is described in the `sp_audioformat` struct given in that callback.

The audio format can change depending on the track being played, so make sure your audio pipeline can deal with that.

Comment: I've played more than 60 tracks and all of them has 44.1kHz sample rate. Do you have any tracks that are not 44.1kHz so I could try? Thanks.

Comment: Sure: spotify:user:jon:playlist:0iZinuqgysEynLxdig8Ca9

Comment: Thanks. I got one song with one 44.1kHz and one music with 48kHz.