# How to play a spotify music stream

Tags: spotify, naudio, bass.dll

First of all, i am new to audio-programming, so bear with me.

I am trying to play spotify music with NAudio or BASS.Net or any other .net audio-library.

As far as i known, libspotify delivers music as raw PCM data. [what is the sample rate of spotify stream (libspotify)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760949/what-is-the-sample-rate-of-spotify-stream-libspotify)

From the spotify docs:
Samples are delivered as integers, see sp_audioformat. One frame consists of the same number of samples as there are channels. I.e. interleaving is on the sample level.

When i try to play a song, spotify makes a callback with a 8192 byte buffer

channels = 2

sample_rate = 44100

num_frames = 2048

I need a little help translating this information to NAudio terms.

I have also tried with a spotify to Bass.Net sample (BASSPlayer.cs). But i haven't heard a single note from my speakers yet. 
I have tried to play an mp3-song with NAudio and Bass.NET and this works fine, so the speaker volume is ok.
https://github.com/Alxandr/SpotiFire/blob/master/SpotiFire.Server/BASSPlayer.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is breakthrough with NAudio. This is what i came up with, by using the trial and error method. I'm not sure if this is the right way to calculate the parameters from sampleRate/channels...

But the song is playing :-)

```
IWavePlayer waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();

using (var pcmStream = new FileStream(PcmFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    const int songDuration = 264000;
    const int sampleRate = 44100;
    const int channels = 2;
    var waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateCustomFormat(WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm, sampleRate * channels, 1, sampleRate * 2 * channels, channels, 16);
    var waveStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(pcmStream, waveFormat);

    waveOutDevice.Init(waveStream);
    waveOutDevice.Play();
    Thread.Sleep(songDuration);
    waveOutDevice.Stop();
    waveStream.Close();
    waveOutDevice.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post. But, what is PcmFile?